# TypeScript and Rollup: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'v4')" when using the uuid package

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, uuid, rollup

I am trying to use the uuid package in my TypeScript project, but I am encountering an error when I try to use the v4 method. The error message is: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'v4')".

I have also included the @rollup/plugin-node-resolve, @rollup/plugin-commonjs, and @rollup/plugin-replace plugins in my rollup.config.js file in order to handle the uuid package, which is a Node.js-style package.
Here is my rollup.config.js file:

```
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import image from "@rollup/plugin-image";
import json from "@rollup/plugin-json";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import nodeResolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import builtins from "rollup-plugin-node-builtins";
import replace from "@rollup/plugin-replace";

export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: {
      file: "dist/bundle.js",
      format: "cjs",
    },
    external: ["uuid"],
    plugins: [
      image(),
      terser(),
      postcss(),
      nodeResolve(),
      commonjs(),
      replace({
        require: "function(){}",
        preventAssignment: true,
      }),
      builtins(),
      typescript({
        tsconfig: "tsconfig.json",
      }),
      json(),
    ],
  },
];
```

In this project, I am using web components for my application. I am using the uuid package to generate unique IDs for these components, but I am encountering an error when I try to use the v4 method.

In one of my web component class, an example usage is like this:

```
import {v4 as uuidv4} from "uuid"

export class ExampleWebComponent extends HTMLElement{
...

private setInitialAttributes() {
    this.setAttribute("customer-id", uuidv4());
  }

...

connectedCallback() {
    if (this.shadowRoot) {
      this.setInitialAttributes();
    }
  }
}
```

And then I import this web component at App.ts file:

```
import { ExampleWebComponent } from "./web-components/ExampleWebComponent";
```

And define it to window.customElements:

```
function defineWebComponents() {
  window.customElements.define("example-web-component", ExampleWebComponent);
}

export default defineWebComponents;
```

and I finally call the defineWebComponents function in index.ts file:

```
import defineWebComponents from "./App";

defineWebComponents();

const newComponent = document.createElement("example-web-component");
console.log(newComponent.getAttribute("customer-id");
```

I was expecting the v4 method to generate a new UUID. I was also expecting the @rollup/plugin-node-resolve, @rollup/plugin-commonjs, and @rollup/plugin-replace plugins to correctly handle the uuid package and allow me to use it in my TypeScript code.

Comment: Does the error say in which file and line the error occurs?

Comment: bundle.js file already have one line. When I press the error, I see this line is red underlined: ....this.setAttribute("customer-id",A.v4())}connectedCallback(){this.shadowRoot&&this.setInitialAttributes()}.....

Comment: I haven't used rollup, but you should be able to get typescript sourcemaps so you can see the original file and line. It seems weird that you get this error, are you sure you haven't made changes to the code to your component class when you got this error? I would expect another error message.

Comment: Isn't it a problem that the bundle.js file even has a script like A=require("uuid")? Browser is not supposed to understand that kind of script right? I believe I configured rollup as it changes something has require(...) to import ... from "...". The things I said may be totally wrong because I'm newbie on using a bundler

Comment: I think it's the commonjs plugin that causes the require(...). CommonJS is meant for server side code, why do you use it if it's going to run in the browser? Try to start with a minimal rollup config and add things later on when needed, instead of the other way around.